# Test iPhone bluetooth features without two iPhones

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, gamekit

I am developing an app that involves bluetooth sharing of files. For development, I don't always have two iPod Touches/iPhones available, but I always have at least one, my personal device. So what I am wondering is, is there a way to simulate the presence of another iPhone for the development of the app?

Before submission, I would test on two iPhones, but just for builds during the initial development stage, is this possible?

Comment: Um, those two answers are totally contradictory. I'm inclined to trust Dennis because he has way more answers, and what Anthony describes seems to good to be true, but I would appreciate some confirmation of this.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply turn on your computers Bluetooth and run the simulator with the app at the same time as running the application on your device. They will be able to see each other.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible , 
The simulator does not support Bluetooth. If you are using GameKit APIs you cannot communicate with your PC's Bluetooth.
So there is no way to simulate , you will have to get 2 iPhone/iPod touch and test.